# FirstOrCreate with only some attributes

Tags: laravel

I want to create a user if not matched:

```
$newUser=User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email,'avatar'=>$user->avatar));
```

But, i also need to store `token` which will be different every time even if other attributes matches. So, i need something like match with only `name`, `email`, `avatar` but also store or update `token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
$newUser = User::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $user->name,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'avatar' => $user->avatar
]);

$newUser->token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

$newUser->save();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of additional values as second parameter:

```
$newUser = User::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email, 'avatar' => $user->avatar],
    ['token' => $token]
);
```

To understand how it works look at source code of [`firstOrCreate()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L255) method.